# Get a list of substrings from a list of strings where the substrings match a certain regular expression

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

This question is for Python 3.6+ (but feel free to answer for lower Pythons for other readers).

I want to extract a substring from each string that matches a regular expression.

Say I have the following:

```
a = ['v-01-001', 'v-01-002', 'v-02-001', 'v-02-002', 'v-02-003', 'v-03-001']
```

I want the last 3 digits of all strings matching `v-02-\d\d\d`, i.e.:

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

My naive attempt:

```
[x[1] for x in list(map(lambda i: re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', i), a)) if x]
```

Can you come up with anything more elegant?

Thanks

Comment: Is regex a requirement?

Comment: Not more elegant, but maybe simpler to read: `d = [elem.split('v-02-')[1] for elem in a if elem.startswith('v-02')]`

Comment: No, regex is not a requirement. I just need to check the prefix is what I want and it ends with 3 digits

Comment: To clarify, by more elegant I mean easier to read and understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import re

a = ['v-01-001', 'v-01-002', 'v-02-001', 'v-02-002', 'v-02-003', 'v-03-001']
pattern = re.compile('v-02-(\d{3})$')
print([m.group(1) for m in map(pattern.match, a) if m])
```

**Output**

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

Also you could use `finditer`:

```
print([m.group(1) for ms in map(pattern.finditer, a) for m in ms])
```

**Output**

```
['001', '002', '003']
```

Comment: @dawg's answer is very comprehensive, but using a compiled regex and then just passing it's search function to the map is perfect - I have to create the regex every time I use it anyway (the first part changes very day so can't store it in a constant) and I was not using the compilation feature!

I went with something like: `[m[1] for m in map(pattern.match, a) if m]`

Answer (score 1):

Four ways to do this.

The first is just a regular 'ole loop:

```
li=[]
for s in a:
    m = re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', s)
    if m:
        li.append(m.group(1))
 # li=['001', '002', '003']
```

Second in two calls to the same regex in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', s).group(1) for s in a if re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', s)]
['001', '002', '003']
```

Third is to use `map`:

```
>>> [m.group(1) for m in map(lambda s: re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', s), a) if m]
['001', '002', '003']
```

Finally, you can flatten the list with `.join` and then use `findall`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bv-02-(\d\d\d)\b', '\t'.join(a))
['001', '002', '003']
```

Or, use `\n` and `re.M` vs two `\b`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^v-02-(\d\d\d)$', '\n'.join(a), flags=re.M)
['001', '002', '003']
```

I would probably write this in that same order if I were writing this bit of code.

What is considered *more elegant* is in the eye of the beholder I suppose. I would consider the last one to be *more elegant.*

---

You can also skip the regex and use Python's string methods:

```
>>> prefix='v-02-'
>>> [e[len(prefix):] for e in filter(lambda s: s.startswith(prefix),a)]
['001', '002', '003']
```

That would likely be the *fastest* if that matters in this case.

---

In December of 2019, there will be a more *elegant* alternative. As defined in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), you will be able to use an assignment statement so you can assign the match and test the match in one step:

```
[m.group(1) for s in a if (m:=re.search(r'v-02-(\d\d\d)', s))]
```

Comment: The last one (PEP 572) is what I was trying to do originally - do a match and then read the match in the first part of the list comprehension - so good to know it's coming!